# É possível simular o safari no windows?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

Queria saber se tem alguma forma de simular o safari no windows, pois em algumas situações o layout que é aplicado no chrome não funciona direito no safari. Com isso queria saber se tem como usar o safari sem necessariamente usar um MAC. A finalidade é inspecionar o elemento e resolver problemas no CSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cara, bastante gente usa o https://www.browserstack.com/mobile-browser-emulator

Acredito que seja a solução mais rápida, existem sim algumas ferramentas para emular o safari se você der um google, ou você pode até ir pra uma solução mais trabalhosa que seria um hackintosh.

Mas como teu problema é só css, da uma googlada por safari web emulator ou browser emulator e você consegue resolver.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Cara show de bola, testei aqui e era o que eu precisava :)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode baixar a versão **5** do `Safari` para `Windows` [**neste link**](http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe). Aparentemente essa será a última versão com suporte para `Windows`.

Fonte: [Where can I download Safari for Windows?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/68837)

Comment: Essa versão não está um pouco antiga? Meu receio é ela não ter suporte a propriedades mais recentes do CSS.

Comment: @DiChrist é meio antiga sim, de 2012

Comment: Hum então não serve no meu caso, mas muito obrigado pela ajuda :)